# How to make a bash script for mac?

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to make this bash script but get this: `Error reading *.docx.  The file doesn’t exist`

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
textutil -convert txt *.docx
cat *.txt | wc -w
```

I'm currently running it from the folder but I'd like to make it a global script I can just call from any current folder.

Comment: How are you running this, from Terminal (with `sh scriptname` or `bash scriptname` or `./scriptname` or something else), or the Finder (by double-clicking?), or what?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it available on your whole system you need to move it to a bin location like so

```
chmod a+rx yourscript.sh && sudo mv yourscript.sh /usr/local/bin/yourscript
```

then you can use it like a normal script in any folder

Comment: You can also convert it to a function and put it on your profile.